# adobe edge animation not rendering in iOS 6

Tags: uiwebview, ios6, adobe-edge

I've created a very simple animation in Adobe Edge Animate that animates a box moving from the bottom right to the top left.

I've imported this file (html + all other files) into my Xcode (v4.5.2) project but get a blank white screen in the simulator. I know my project is fine because if I copy a static html page into the project it renders correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

since the difference between your project and the test page is that your project links to javascript files while the test page did not, maybe you should run a test with a page that calls a simple javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few threads on adobe forum about some problems with projects opened on ios 6 devices. Maby this also concerns your project.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4767681

Try to call this method and add some js code to your webview's document:

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.requestAnimationFrame = window.setTimeout;"];